# Primefaces - Dialog content does not fit in popup panel

Tags: primefaces, datatable, dialog, resizable

I am trying to display a datatable in a popup using the Dialog Framework.
My code is based in the example published here: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/df/data.xhtml

I am using this piece of code in my backbean to show the popup:

```java
    public void chooseImage() {
       String page = "ImageChooser";

       Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
       properties.put("modal", true);
       properties.put("resizable", true);
       properties.put("draggable", true);
       properties.put("width", 400);
       properties.put("height", 400);

       RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog(page, properties, null);
}
```

And this is part of my ImagerChooser.xhtml page:

```html
<h:body>
         <h:form> 

                <p:dataTable var="img" value="#{imageManagerController.imageList}" rows="5"   layout="grid" paginator="true"
                    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                    rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10"  >

                    <p:column field="#{img.name}">
                            <h:outputText value="#{img.name}" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</code>
```

The problem i have is that the rendered datatable is always wider that my dialog (640px). Then, I need to use the scrollbars. How can i make this datatable resizable (depending on dialog size)? is there any auto-fit feature?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by adding these properties in my backbean before opening the dialog.

```
properties.put("contentWidth", 650);
properties.put("contentheight", 660);
```

I hope it helps